# Empty Text in TFS HtmlFieldControl

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

TFS 2013 on-premise, VS 2015 client.

I've edited my Bug Work Item Template to include descriptive empty text in the "Steps to Reproduce" tab.

The empty text displays properly in Visual Studio client (VS 2015 as of this writing), but will not display in the web client. I'm prompting bug work items to include descriptive text in the "Steps to Reproduce" control. It renders as expected in Visual Studio client app:
[image: VS client app]

But nothing in the web interface:
[image: web client]

There's a related question that's already been asked (and unanswered), but I don't have the reputation to comment, and the mods deleted my "answer," which really clarified the issue from the original question.

Has anyone discovered a solution that will render in both Visual Studio AND the web client?

Comment: Which update to 2013 are you running?

Comment: TFS 2013, Update 4

Answer (score 0):

Tested in TFS 2015.1 + VS 2015, could reproduce your scenario. The Empty Text can be shown in both VS and web access for a FieldControl type, but for HtmlFieldControl, the Empty Text only can be shown in VS.

I also customize a field to use HtmlFieldControl, same result. The Empty Text can't be shown in web access.

It's suggested to submit a UserVoice at website below: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015